# QWidget Geometry() not updating

Tags: qt, pyside, qwidget

I have `QWidget`s lined up in a `QVBoxLayout` inside a `QScrollArea` with `setWidgetResizable(True)`

When I resize one of the `QWidget`s, the `QWidget`s relocate themselves accordingly in the graphical user interface, but their `geometry()` property doesn't reflect that, `geometry().x()` and `geometry().y()` both remain the same before and after relocation.

The only method I have found so far to update the `x()` and `y()` coordinates is to `hide()` and `show()` the `QScrollArea`.

I have tried `update()`, `updateGeometry()` and `repaint()` without any success.

Here is a sample test code that I made to summarize the problem :

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.showMaximized()
        self.widget_window = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollarea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.v_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.test_1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Test 1')
        self.test_2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Test 2')
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.test_1)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.test_2)
        self.widget_window.setLayout(self.v_layout)
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollarea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollarea.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.widget_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollarea)
        print(self.test_2.geometry().x())
        print(self.test_2.geometry().y())
        self.test_1.setFixedHeight(1000)
        #uncommenting the following next two lines, solves the problem
        #self.scrollarea.hide()
        #self.scrollarea.show()
        print(self.test_2.geometry().x())
        print(self.test_2.geometry().y())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My questions are :

1. Is there a better solution ?
2. Isn't `updateGeometry()` supposed to actually update the `geometry()` ?
3. Why is this behavior happening ? (i.e why does it update graphically but not programmatically ?)
4. Can using `hide()` and `show()` successively cause some problems in other contexts (window flickering or something else...) ?

Comment: How is the QScrollArea added to the VLayout in this example?

Comment: Actually, the layout is for a QWidget that is the internal widget of the QScrollArea. The QScrollArea isn't part of any layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the GUI, it's not instantaneous. It's performed when you give the control to the event loop. In this case, it's done *after* `__init__` completes, which is obviously after all your `print`s. Therefore, you'll see the old position.

`hide/show` forces an update at that point. That's why you get correct values. However, this is not the best way, because you might observe flicker while `hide/show` does its job.

Better way would be telling the event loop to process events before continuing. This will ensure that the GUI is updated:

```
    #...
    print(self.test_2.geometry().x())
    print(self.test_2.geometry().y())
    self.test_1.setFixedHeight(1000)
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
    print(self.test_2.geometry().x())
    print(self.test_2.geometry().y())
    #...
```

**PS**: I'm assuming, you have good reasons to do this. Most of the time, you won't care when the GUI is updated.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Still one thing I don't understand, how can the GUI update itself without updating `geometry().x()` and `geometry().y()` values ? Generally, it is the opposite that happens (i.e code updating but not GUI) ?

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou: When you call `self.test_1.setFixedHeight(1000)`, neither GUI nor `geometry` is updated. Visual updates or recalculation of `geometry` isn't instantaneous. It's "queued". Once Qt event loop gets a chance to process those events, updates are performed. `.processEvents()` basically "pauses" the `__init__` and lets the Qt event loop to take care of those update events right there.

Comment: In other words, in your original version, GUI *is not* updated between those print calls. It happens afterwards.